# Symfony request files empty after file upload from Nextjs's API route

Tags: javascript, php, next.js13, symfony6

I'm trying to upload a file from NextJS client towards Symfony endpoint VIA NextJS API route.

I'm using React state to handle form submission in the client side like so:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import Head from "next/head";
import axios from "axios";
import {toast} from "react-toastify";
import Loader from "@/components/Loader";
import {useToken} from "@/contexts/JWTContext";
import {useRouter} from "next/router";

function NewBanner(props) {

    const {jwt} = useToken();

    const router = useRouter();

    const {pid} = router.query;

    const [file, setFile] = useState(null)

    const [loader, setLoader] = useState(false);

    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
    
        const asset = new FormData();
        asset.append("file", file)

        for (const value of asset.values()) {
            console.log(value);
        }

        axios.post(
            '/api/assets/banners/new',
            asset,
            {
                headers: {
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${jwt}`,
                    'Content-Type': file.type
                },
                withCredentials: true
            }
        )
            .then(r => {
                setLoader(false);
                toast.success(r.data.message, {
                    position: "top-center",
                    autoClose: 5000,
                    hideProgressBar: false,
                    closeOnClick: true,
                    pauseOnHover: true,
                    draggable: true,
                    progress: undefined,
                    theme: "dark",
                })
                router.push(`/`).then()
            })
            .catch(e => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    setLoader(false);
                    toast.error(e.message, {
                        position: "top-center",
                        autoClose: 5000,
                        hideProgressBar: false,
                        closeOnClick: true,
                        pauseOnHover: true,
                        draggable: true,
                        progress: undefined,
                        theme: "dark",
                    })
                    router.push(`/`).then()
                }, 60000)
            })
    }

    return (
        <>
            <Head>
                <title>Add new picture/video</title>
                <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
                <link rel="icon" href="/public/favicon.ico" />
            </Head>
            <main className="pt-12 lg:pt-24">
                {
                    loader
                        ?
                        <Loader/>
                        :
                        <div className="px-6 lg:px-8">
                            <h3 className="mb-4 text-xl font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-white">Spark interest and boost sales: introduce new banners regularly.</h3>
                            <form className="space-y-6" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                                <div>
                                    <label htmlFor="file" className="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-white">Attachment</label>
                                    <input onChange={(e) => setFile(e.target.files[0])} defaultValue={file} type="file" name="file" id={`new-file-${props.pid}`} className="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-600 dark:border-gray-500 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white" required/>
                                </div>
                                <button type="submit" className="w-full text-white bg-teal-800 effect hover:bg-grn focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-300 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm px-5 py-2.5 text-center dark:bg-blue-600 dark:hover:bg-blue-700 dark:focus:ring-blue-800">Done</button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                }
            </main>
        </>
    );
}

export default NewBanner;
```

now i use nextJS api routes to communicate with symfony endpoints, and in that case i'm handling communication and file upload through ***/api/assets/banners/new*** .
there i'm using a third party package **formidable** to parse the FormData object sent from client side and recuperate its *files* and *fields* like so:

```
import axios from "axios";
import formidable, {errors as formidableErrors, IncomingForm} from "formidable";
import fs from "fs";

export default async function handler(req, res) {

    let response = {};
    let data = {};

    const token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];

    const postedConfig = {
        headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
            "Content-Type": `${req.headers['content-type']}`
        }
    };

    try {

            const asyncParse = (req) =>
                new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    const form = new IncomingForm();
                    form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {
                        if (err) return reject(err);
                        console.log("files: ", files.file)
                        console.log("fields: ", fields)

                        resolve({ fields, files });
                    });
                });

            response = await asyncParse(req);

            const formData = new FormData()
            formData.append("banner_form[bannerFile]", response.files.file[0], response.files.file[0].originalFilename)

            console.log("file: ", Object.keys(response.files.file[0]))
            console.log("filepath: ", response.files.file[0].filepath)
            console.log("filename: ", response.files.file[0].newFilename)
            console.log("originalFilename: ", response.files.file[0].originalFilename)

            data = await axios.post(
                `http://localhost:8000/api/new/banner`,
                formData,
                postedConfig
            );

    }
    catch (e) {
        res.writeHead(e.httpCode || 400, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
        res.end(String(e));
    }

    res.status(200).json(data.data);
}

export const config = {
    api: {
        bodyParser: false
    }
};
```

the issue is that I cannot read data properly inside my symfony endpoint as
`$request->files` is empty so i cannot read any data to process it using symfony form-types plus the content-length seems to be descresing with a huge amount since the original file( test with picture ) is 864kb and the content-length received by symfony is 375b !
I wonder if something wrong happened at the time of NextJS api route processing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue, it was a little tricky so it could help someone else for future readings:

when i was sending data from client component to the API route in nextjs all data (the file) was being uploaded as expected.

but when i was parsing the form using **formidable**, I indeed got the right file size and every detail was uploaded as original.

Then I send request to symfony endpoint and while inspecting the `$request` body, I saw that a string representation of the file is being send to port 8000 not the actual file itself and that's why the ***Content-Length*** was equal to *375b*...

So i figured a solution for that by creating the file inside the API route and then send it to port 8000 (symfony)...

here's the sample code :

```
response = await asyncParse(req);

const formData = new FormData()
const filePath = response.files.file[0].filepath;
const file = new Blob([await readFile(filePath)], { type: lookup(filePath) });
formData.append("banner_form[bannerFile]", file, response.files.file[0].originalFilename)

data = await axios.post(
`http://localhost:8000/api/new/banner`,
formData,
postedConfig
);
```

make sure of right import as well:

```
import { readFile } from "node:fs/promises"
import { lookup } from "mime-types"
```